# Flex Box overlapping on IE11 and Safari on IPhone

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overlapping

The website I designed, is not properly displayed by IPhone and IExplorer11. I've checked it on

windows (chrome, FFox) **OK**

android (chrome) **OK**

Ipad Safari, Chrome **OK**

Iphone Safari and IE11 **overlapping problem**

The web site is displayed correctly on IE11 on big screen whenever flex-direction:column media query works overlapping problem occurs.

I have one basis div #main contains two other basis divs #right and #left

My css codes for basis divs are:

```
#main{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: relative;
}


#left{
    -webkit-box-flex: 4;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 4;
    -ms-flex-positive: 4;
    flex-grow: 4;

    -webkit-flex-basis: 66.66%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 66.66%;
    flex-basis: 66.66%;

    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    -ms-flex-negative: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;

    margin-right: 7.5px;
    position: relative;
}


#right{
    -webkit-box-flex: 2;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 2;
    -ms-flex-positive: 2;
    flex-grow: 2;

    -webkit-flex-basis: 33.33%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 33.33%;
    flex-basis: 33.33%;


    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    -ms-flex-negative: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;

    margin-left: 7.5px;
    position: relative;
}

@media (max-width: 755px){
    #main{
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

When I check the website on Iphone Safari and IE11 (small screen) right section overlaps on left section.

I have tried to some solution but none of them did't work. (such as set min-height)

I am waiting for your comments.
Thank you for reading.

[here is the link to the page](http://www.csstr.com/FS/david/)

Comment: I can better assist you if you provide a link to the working code.

Comment: Of course here is the  [link](http://www.csstr.com/FS/david/)

Comment: Thanks for this. Revealing that the overlapping problem also happens in IE11 gave me a way to test it live to solve my overlapping problem. A switch to `flex-direction: row` and `flex-wrap: wrap` solved it for my design.

Answer (score 4):

This fixes everything for me:

```
@media (max-width: 755px){
  #main {
    display: block; /* remove flex parent */
  }
}
```

or this version:

```
@media (max-width: 755px){
  #left, #right {
    flex-basis: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andy. It works perfectly on IE11. I am gonna test it on IPhone tomorrow, but I am sure It'll work on IPhone as well.

Comment: Things were broken in Mac/Safari, too, which is also where I tested. Hopefully mobile Safari, which I didn't test yet, plays well with my answer.